# Is accessing mapped device memory slow (in terms of latency)?

Tags: c, memory, io, dma, pci

I know the question is vague.. but here is what I hope to learn: the MCU directs some part of memory address to devices on the PCI bus, hence in theory user/kernel code can directly read/write device memory as if it were  main memory. But data in and out of PCI Express devices are packaged/serialized/transmitted in lanes, which means each read/write incurs significant overhead, such as packaging (add headers) and un-packaging. So that means it is not ideal for user/kernel to read device memory a byte at a time, instead it should do some sort of bulk transfer. If so, what is the preferred mechanism and API?

BTW, I know there is DMA, but it seems to me that DMA does not require device memory to be directly mapped into main memory address space - DMA is about letting device access main memory, and my question is the other way, letting user/kernel access device memory. So I am guessing it is not related to the question above, is that correct?

Comment: The only reasonable answer is "it depends" — and it depends on many factors (most of which I probably don't know about).

Comment: You are correct that DMA concerns a device accessing main memory. It is somewhat related to your question, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: found this link to be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/36463477/2762678

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, accessing memory-mapped I/O (MMIO) is slow.

The primary reason that it is slow is that it is typically uncacheable,
so every access has to go all the way to the device.
In x86 systems, which I am most familiar with, cacheable memory is accessed in 64-byte chunks,
even though processor instructions typically access memory in 1, 2, 4, or 8 byte chunks.
If multiple processor instructions access adjacent cacheable memory locations, all but the first access are satisfied from the cache. For similar accesses to device memory, every access incurs the full latency to the device and back.

The second reason is that the path from the processors to memory are critical to performance and are highly optimized.
The path to devices has always been slow, so software is designed to compensate for that, and optimizing the performance of MMIO isn't a priority.

Another related reason is that PCI has ordering rules that require accesses to be buffered and processed in a strict order.
The memory system can handle ordering in a much more flexible way. For example, a dirty cache line may be written to memory at any convenient time. MMIO accesses must be performed precisely in the order that they are executed by the CPU.

The best way to do bulk transfer of data to a device is to have the device itself perform DMA, "pulling" the data from memory into the device, rather than "pushing" it from the CPU to the device. (This also reduces the load on the CPU, freeing it to do other useful work.)

Comment: Thanks, @prl. "The best way to do bulk transfer of data to a device is to have the device itself perform DMA" - then why does PCIe devices have memory mapped in the first place? If they map a few bytes and use them as control registers that would be understandable, but they can map more than a few mega bytes.